# How to make such a dialogue?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I want to make a guide in my application in this style:

[image: what is it?]

But I don't know how it is named and what to look for in order to reproduce such a guide.
Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: this is what u need https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/

Comment: It is extactly what i meant, tkanks !!!!

Comment: Note: In Android, `Dialog` means a modal pop over. This kind of UI is a `Pager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `ViewPager`. Each page (Fragment) has an illustration and a text at the center, then there is an indicator at the bottom. [Such as this one](https://github.com/romandanylyk/PageIndicatorView).

Note that now you don't have to use fragments for ViewPager, you can use [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) as a Horizontal RecyclerView!

Comment: There's a lot more discussion/guidance about ViewPager2 here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-viewpager2/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

This is known as an Intro Slider. You can look up several examples on Github. 
This enables you to onboard your user when they are using your app for the first time. It uses ViewPager to create this effect.

Good luck.